# How to link kernel functions to user-space program?

Tags: linux, linker, kernel, freebsd, static-linking

I have a user-space program (Capstone). I would like to use it in FreeBSD kernel. I believe most of them have the same function name, semantics and arguments (in FreeBSD, the kernel `printf` is also named `printf`). First I built it as `libcapstone.a` library, and link my program with it. Since the include files are different between Linux user-space and FreeBSD kernel, the library cannot find symbols like `sprintf`, `memset` and `vsnprintf`. How could I make these symbols (from FreeBSD kernel) visible to `libcapstone.a`?

If directly including header files like `<sys/systm.h>` in Linux user-space source code, the errors would be like `undefined type u_int or u_char`, even if I add `-D_BSD_SOURCE` to `CFLAGS`.

Additionally, any other better ways to do this?

Comment: First you say you want to use kernel functions in a user-space program.  Then you talk about what sounds like using user-space functions in a kernel module.  Which is it?

Comment: Put user-space program in kernel, as a library. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need ; take a look at kernel man pages, eg "man 9 printf".  They list required includes at the top.

Note, however, that you're trying to do something *really* hard.  Some basic functions (eg printf) might be there; others differ completely (eg malloc(9)), and most POSIX APIs are simply not there.  You won't be able to use open(2), socket(2), or fork(2).